# MySQL Trigger Not Executing like it should

Tags: mysql, triggers

I wrote the trigger below, but when I insert into the table it doesn't capitalize the inserted word, like it is supposed to. (no errors either). Any possible solutions? 
(I have an employee and an employee2 table, since I read you cant have the trigger in the table it is trying to update).

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS mytrigger$$
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger before INSERT ON employee FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 update employee2
 SET employee2.FName = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(employee2.FName, 1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(employee2.FName, 2)));
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: change the event `AFTER INSERT` if you run `UPDATE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have triggers on the table you are trying to update, you just can't run UPDATE queries.  Instead, you modify the data before it is inserted:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS mytrigger$$
CREATE TRIGGER mytrigger before INSERT ON employee FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.FName = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(NEW.FName, 1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(NEW.FName, 2)));
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

The "NEW" keyword gives you access to the data that is going to be inserted.

Comment: It just seems too good to be true; too easy but THANK YOU, you have no idea how fried my brain was trying to figure this out. In all honesty, i probably would never have figure out i could use new, now I will never forget!

Comment: Just out of curiousity, If I wanted the same trigger to also work before updates ( so to work before updates and before inserts) would I have to create a second trigger?

Comment: Yes, you would have to create a second trigger.  With update triggers you get access to both the OLD and NEW values.